# How to support large smartphones and phables but not tablets

Tags: android

Right now I am developing an app which works fine on smartphones and in theory also on phablets but not on tablets. The width of a tablet it too large so I need new layouts for tablets. But the app is fine on a LG G3 for example, i tested it with my own device.

But I am having trouble on how to support large smartphones but not tablets. It looks like, I either support everything or nothing.

```
<compatible-screens>
   <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />      
    </compatible-screens>
```

This is the part of my manifest file which shows what I support. I would really like to add the "large" screensize for phablets, but then I am supporting tablets at the same time.

Any ideas how to accomplish this almost impossible feature?

Comment: The distinction between a phablet and a tablet is increasingly arbitrary. Maybe let the user decide if they want to use it on their device.

Comment: take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764325/exclude-tablets-from-apk-publishing

Comment: take a look at this [question].

[question]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764325/exclude-tablets-from-apk-publishing

Answer (score 0):

you could use this library to get user device: [android.os.build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Here's an example:

```
String _DEVICE = android.os.Build.DEVICE;
```

Comment: Currently, your answer is just a link. You should either delete your answer and make it a comment OR give a code sample/explain how it would be used. I also don't really think this will do what OP is asking unless an excessive amount of work is put forth.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeking is determined by your distribution channel. The Play Store, AFAIK, [still does not honor `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#requiresSmallest), which would be the only means in the manifest of specifying what you want. Other distribution channels might support that attribute -- you would have to contact them.