# How to restrict app installing in Tablets but allow in Samsung Note 4 device

Tags: android

I want to restrict installing application in Tablets.I have set supported device on Android manifest file.

```
    <!-- all small size screens -->

    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />

</compatible-screens>
```

The above code is working fine but my application does not support on Samsung Note 4 devices.I Want to allow installing Note 4 so which parameter need to add on manifest file?

Comment: Maybe you can do it directly from [Play console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017?hl=en&ctx=go). Also see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17764338/3419997)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to exclude devices whichever you want from the developer console in your case. By default it marks all devices to check when device is compatible with your hardware requested.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: @Rajkiran May I know what you want to know in detail

Comment: I question about application on Google play store supported device list.I require my application support only android device not in android tablets.So I add supported device(Screen) parameter on app manifest file.But problem is I can not seen my application on Google store in my Samsung Note 4 device.