# Android - Declaring an App is Only for phones

Tags: android, google-play

I know there are answers to this question, but they are all 2+ years old.

What is the updated way of making sure your app only ends up on mobiles, and not tablets, tvs, watches, etc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764325/exclude-tablets-from-apk-publishing

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You should look at this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

---

In your manifest, you declare this:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

according to the Android documentation(see link at top) this is the way to support phones only. But something to keep in mind is to also support xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. Screen size is the attribute that is the key. S6 edge has xxxhdpi screen size, so this is something you should keep in mind.

I have modified the above snipped to include xxxhdpi densities. Note that the density is **irrelevant to the size of the screen**. A device can be 3 inches but be xxxhdpi.

From what I read in the documentation, simply declaring the above in the manifest should prevent tablets from downloading the app.

---

As for supporting watches and TV's, this is something you **specifically have to support**. Android watches for an instance, require the Android Wear API. You cannot run an app designed with the "normal" API and use it on a watch. Same applies to TVs, you specifically have to support it. There may be a custom API there too, not to sure as I have not hav anything to do with Android TV

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it worked fine.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```